# Integral domain $A $ such that $A\to K(A)$ is epimorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Sorry for my bad English.
I want to the naming for integral domain which have next property.

$A$ is commutative domain, and $K(A)$ is fraction of $A$. Then, natural inclusion $A\to K(A)$ is epimorphism in category of commutative rings.

For example, ring of integers $\mathbb Z$ have this property.

If this name exists, please tell me thanks.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "fraction of $A$", but, If $K(A)$ means the field of fractions of the integral domain $A$, then the inclusion of $A$ into $K(A)$ is always an epimorphism in the category of rings.

Comment: Sorry, I mean “fraction of $A$“ is the field of fractions of the integral domain $A$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any commutative ring $R$ and any multiplicatively closed subset $S\subset R$, the morphism $R \to S^{-1}R$ is an epimorphism. In particular, this holds for any integral domain $A$ with $S=A\setminus \{0\}$ and $S^{-1}A=K(A)$